# C# CodedUI:Unable to find controls

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I am finding it strange that I'm unable to find the control if I set `Playback.PlaybackSettings.SearchTimeout`, if I remove then it`s finding the control I want.

Below is my code:

```
Playback.PlaybackSettings.SearchTimeout=5000;

WinTabPage tab=new WinTabPage();
this.Tab = new WinTabPage(this);
this.Tab.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.Name] = "Some Tab";
Tab.WaitForControlEnabled(3000);
Mouse.Click(Tab);
```

Error I`m getting is: Playback failed to find the control with the given search properties.

But the same works if remove `searchTimeOut` which I have set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search timeout property on Playback settings determines the max amount of time coded ui engine will search for a contorl before failing the test with exception.

it's in miliseconds - so for your example you define max 5 sec search time.

the default value is 2 minutes.

try this slide share for more information: 
[advanced Codedui slide share](http://www.slideshare.net/ShaiRaiten/coded-ui-ws)

Comment: That`s a greate link to learn from. Thanks a lot. I`ll go through it.